# ScriptResource.axd requests return HTTP 302

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis-6, dotnetnuke, http-status-code-302

The DNN application I develop has this familiar problem in the deployment env (Win 2003/IIS 6). From all resources I've searched only one came close to my situation. i.e this request returning 404 instead of 302 I get.

Common suggestions like aspnet reinstallation, web.config settings, removing 'verify file exists' in IIS handler settings are all tried with nor results.

Any Clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! Thank you for everyone who spend any time on this.

I've managed to fix this. The Deployment server time was wrong! It was 12 hours earlier than the actual time. Although I expected a HTTP status of 5xx. Well...C'est la vie!

So when you get a 'Sys is undefined' error add this solution to the list.

> CHECK THE SERVER TIME